# how to set the minimum length of a single line text in sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, column-validation, presaveaction

I have already set the maximum length, but now I need the user to enter not less than a certain amount

This is the script I'm using :

```
function PreSaveAction() {
var control = getElementByID("IBAN(24 Digits Alpha Numeric)");
 if(control.value.length < 24) 
 { 
  alert("The length in this field should not be less than 24 chars"); 
  return false; // Cancel the item save process 
 } 
else { return true ;}
}
```

Comment: Is this working for you or not? may be getElementByID is not returning anything.

Comment: @GaneshSanap No, this isn't working for me. And yes, I too think that getElementByID is not returning anything. What would be the correct way to get value from the input field?

Comment: Try the solution given below. let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @GaneshSanap no it doesnt, since i get a word count/limit error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SharePoint OOTB Solution**:

**Use Column Validation**:

1. Go to your list settings.
2. Click on your text column.
3. Move to column validation section and enter below expression:

   `=LEN([your column name])>24`

And you can enter some message in user message section.

**JavaScript Approach**:

Try using below code:

Assuming the display name of your field is "IBAN(24 Digits Alpha Numeric)".

```
var control = document.querySelector("input[title^='IBAN(24 Digits Alpha Numeric)']");
```

Comment: i have already used column validation for something else, so when i add this line of code, it gives me a word count error :)

Comment: Can you post the existing formula? so that we can merge the formula and see if it works.

Comment: =AND(IF(ISERROR(FIND(",",[IBAN(24 Digits Alpha Numeric)])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("&",[IBAN(24 Digits Alpha Numeric)])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("!",[IBAN(24 Digits Alpha Numeric)])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("@",[IBAN(24 Digits Alpha Numeric)])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("#",[IBAN(24 Digits Alpha Numeric)])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("$",[IBAN(24 Digits Alpha Numeric)])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("%",[IBAN(24 Digits Alpha Numeric)])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("*",[IBAN(24 Digits Alpha Numeric)])),TRUE),IF(ISERROR(FIND("-",[IBAN(24 Digits Alpha Numeric)])),TRUE))

Comment: The text you entered for the Validation Formula must be 1024 characters or fewer, including the leading '=' character.

Comment: Tried using the JavaScript approach but it does not work :(

Comment: Try adding breakpoint at `var control=` line and debug the code. see what is returning in control varibale. Or post the screenshot of textbox field from inspect element window.

Comment: Have you tried this?

Comment: No, trying to do it through column validation.

Comment: Does any of the above approaches answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code to get the control element:

```
var control = WebForm_GetElementById("IBAN(24 Digits Alpha Numeric)");
```